# Aligning values in csv file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, csv

I have a csv file with the following information this csv file was created by combining results from `aws rds describe-db-instances` and
`aws rds describe-reserved-db-instances` and by parsing the results with jq then I `paste`d together the csv files.

```
DB Instance Identifier,Reservation ID,State
alpha-db-dev,alpha-db-dev-26aug2022,active
alpha-db-prod,alpha-db-prod-26aug2022,active
alpha-db-staging,alpha-db-staging-26aug2022,active
beta-db-dev-primary,beta-db-dev-8dec2021,active
beta-db-prod-primary,charlie-db-dev-8dec2021,active
beta-db-prod-replica,charlie-db-staging-loadtest-8dec2021,active
beta-db-staging-primary,,
charlie-db-dev,,
charlie-db-prod-dms,,
charlie-db-prod-dms-replica,,
charlie-db-staging,,
charlie-db-staging-loadtest,,
```

What I'm trying to do is match the first few words of the 2nd column and the first few words of the 1st column.

The result should be like this

```
DB Instance Identifier,Reservation ID,State
alpha-db-dev,alpha-db-dev-26aug2022,active
alpha-db-prod,alpha-db-prod-26aug2022,active
alpha-db-staging,alpha-db-staging-26aug2022,active
beta-db-dev-primary,beta-db-dev-8dec2021,active
beta-db-prod-primary,,
beta-db-prod-replica,,
beta-db-staging-primary,,
charlie-db-dev,charlie-db-dev-8dec2021,active
charlie-db-prod-dms,,
charlie-db-prod-dms-replica,,
charlie-db-staging,,
charlie-db-staging-loadtest,charlie-db-staging-loadtest-8dec2021,active
```

Basically what I would want to happen is that in the csv file, I would want to match the `charlie-db-staging-loadtest` with `charlie-db-staging-loadtest-8dec2021` to be in the same row.

I have been clueless on what to do next and how to match the texts between the column DB Instance Identifier and Reservation ID. More over, how to move matching texts to be in the same row. So I have no attempts on solving this so far.

I am open to using any commands as long as it would work with bash. And I would really appreciate the breakdown of commands as I will be applying this to a somewhat similar but not quite the same csv file that has tons of data that would be way too big to put here.

I have been playing around with sed and awk but I can't seem to make it work just yet. But maybe I'm thinking of the wrong commands here. Any insights would be helpful.

Thank you so much!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I think you should probably solve this at an earlier stage, e.g. with better `jq` filters.

Comment: Quite possibly! Thanks for linking the XY problem dilemma. First time I've heard about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Thor is absolutely right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715848/aligning-values-in-csv-file/715926#comment1356500_715848) but in case you're in a hurry to wrap this up and so you or others with a similar problem can learn how to do such things for yourself in future, here's how to do what you asked for using any awk and a 2-pass approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == FNR {
    id = $2
    sub(/-[^-]+$/,"",id)
    vals[id] = $2 OFS $3
    next
}
{ print (FNR>1 ? $1 OFS vals[$1] : $0) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
DB Instance Identifier,Reservation ID,State
alpha-db-dev,alpha-db-dev-26aug2022,active
alpha-db-prod,alpha-db-prod-26aug2022,active
alpha-db-staging,alpha-db-staging-26aug2022,active
beta-db-dev-primary,
beta-db-prod-primary,
beta-db-prod-replica,
beta-db-staging-primary,
charlie-db-dev,charlie-db-dev-8dec2021,active
charlie-db-prod-dms,
charlie-db-prod-dms-replica,
charlie-db-staging,
charlie-db-staging-loadtest,charlie-db-staging-loadtest-8dec2021,active
```

I think it's very obvious what it's doing but if after reading the man pages, googling, adding `print` statements to track variables values, etc. (so you can learn more about awk in general) you can't figure it out then just ask specific questions in comments and I'll be happy to answer them. To learn awk in general, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thank you so much Ed! This was EXTREMELY helpful!! And does exactly what I would like to do. Learning awk right sure is a bit daunting. If it's not too much to ask. I'd like to apply this to a similar csv file. I tried moving around the variables and calls for columns but I can't make it work, all I'm getting are either a bunch of `,` or getting the wrong values. I've edited the question to fit in the csv file i'm trying to edit. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Please put the question back as it was when you got answers, as now my answer makes no sense to anyone else looking for an answer to a similar question, and then ask a new question with the new data if you like.

Comment: Got it! Returned it to the previous question, I have created a new question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716268/using-awk-to-align-values-in-correct-rows-in-csv-files and your answer would be greatly greatly greatly appreciated. Thank you so much Ed. I'll buy you a coffee once payday comes! Truly appreciate your effort and time answering my queries.